# SAPUI5 get binding context of row by index

Tags: sapui5

In my application I have a sap.m.table. The data is in a JSON model and bound to the table. In my function I need to loop all table rows and check each visible row for the value of a specific property. I can determine the visible rows like this:

```
sap.ui.getCore().byId("myTableId").getAggregation("items")
```

However, I was not able to use some function like `getBindingContext` to determine the property values of the row.

Any hint how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

you should not use directly `sap.ui.getCore().byId()` but `this.getView().byId()` where `this` is the controller itself.

Anyway, every item of the aggregation has a binding context available. It depends on which is the name of the model you are using to bind context to.

In my example I'm accessing the binding context object of the first item of the table and you can do that like this:

```
sap.ui.getCore().byId("__xmlview1--idPartnerList").getAggregation("items")[0].getBindingContext().getObject()
```

Otherwise, if you are accessing the view directly from the control (as you should) you can do like this

```
this.getView().byId("idPartnerList").getAggregation("items")[0].getBindingContext().getObject()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not able to use `this.getView().byId()` since I created the table in my controller. I can only access it with `sap.ui.getCore()`. When I try to use `getBindingContext().getObject()` on one of the items, I get an error because `getBindingContext()` is already undefined...

Comment: Without the code, I cannot help you. If the context is undefined it's because you are using a model name (which I'm not in the example) or your items have no context at that specific time (which is really strange). Anyway, you should follow the MVC principles and define views and bindings on the XML views.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the **bindingContext** of each row in a table using below code:

If you have **alias name** in your local json model.

```
sap.ui.getCore().byId("myTableId").getAggregation("items")[0].getBindingContext("<alias model name>").getObject();
```

Else, if you do not have **alias name** in your local json model.

```
sap.ui.getCore().byId("myTableId").getAggregation("items")[0].getBindingContext().getObject();
```

Thank you.